# Trying to change jQuery click handler of parent fires off new click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm experiencing some (to me) unexpected behavior from event listeners using jQuery, but I expect it's just the underlying Javascript functionality that's confusing me. I think there's a good chance that the answer to my problem is fairly simple, but I can't figure it out.

I have a `<div>` with a status in it, which is 'New' by default. I want to be able to click on that `<div>` and bring up a pair of buttons, one which allow you to replace the 'New' status text with 'Complete', and another which will cancel the action, removing the buttons and displaying the 'New' status text again.

I can get everything to work, and it all works fine if I use a different element to display the buttons, but when I try to temporarily replace the text in the `<div>`, something strange happens.

When I try to reset the original click event for the `<div>`, what appears to happen is that the click on the cancel button also triggers the just-set click event as well. This re-displays the buttons, so it looks like the cancel button just didn't work. (I was stuck on that for a while...)

I've made a very simple JSFiddle that shows the problem I'm having:

https://jsfiddle.net/pn1q658w/4/

And there's also a slightly modified version that shows things working as long as I've got the cancel button in a different element than the element where I'm resetting the original click function:

https://jsfiddle.net/pn1q658w/3/

I assume this has something to do with the fact that I don't completely understand the way that the timing of these events works. The same click appears to be firing off an event that is set during an action taken because of that click, which I didn't expect, but may very well be how things are supposed to work.

My question is how can I have a click event which is trying to set a click listener on a parent element not fire off the new click at the same time?

Or, if I've completely misunderstood the nature of my mistake, an indication of what I have done wrong would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Just like @charlietfl said, I bleive that the simplest way is to separe the elements everyone with his own class, See **[WORKED FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/pn1q658w/8/)** :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="elementId">
    <span class='text'>New</span>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(function(){

    var newBtn = '<button class="btn btn-default complete">Complete?</button><button class="btn btn-default cancel">X</button>';

    //Handle the click in the text span         
    $("#elementId").on("click","span.text",function(e){
        $(this).html(newBtn);    
    });

    //Handle the click in the complete button         
    $("#elementId").on("click","button.complete",function(e){
        $('#elementId').html("<span class='text'>Completed</span>");
    });

    //Handle the click in the cancel button 
    $("#elementId").on("click","button.cancel",function(e){
        $('#elementId').html("<span class='text'>New</span>");
    });

});
```

I hope that this code help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, I think I understand how this other way of structuring things makes it much easier to manage. I really appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Need to understand that when you click on an element inside another element...you are still clicking on the parent as well.

Events "bubble" or "propagate" up the DOM tree all the way to the document...unless told to stopPropagation()

What you are seeing is expected behavior.

You can prevent that bubbling by:

```
$(selector).click(function(event){

   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

There are some oddities in your code that could defintiely be streamlined
First you pass an element to the handler...then take properties of that elemnt to create a selector to find exactly the same element again in the DOM

```
var cellId = element.id;
$('#' + cellId)
```

Can be simplified to

```
$(element);// doesn't require searching for the ID
```

And can also be stored as a variable instead of doing the same selector over and over

```
var $el = $(element);
$el.off('click');
var oldCellContent = $el.text();
```

These simplifications are more efficient and easier to read

Comment: That does seem to work for me! Adding that to the function did stop the new click event from firing. I'd never seen anything about stopPropagation() before, but I understand why it works in this case.  

Is that the right way to do this, though? Or is that just the best way to make what I've done work?  Is there a better way that I should have set things up in the first place?  

It's good to know that this is how things are supposed to work. I guess I had expected the bubble up through the DOM tree to happen before I set the click listener on the parent, but I can tell I was wrong. :)

Comment: well i didn't want to try to get too deep into it but all the event handling is a mess...you remove the click handler then add it again inside button clicks. Suggest you rethink all of this

Comment: It is acceptable practice but in most cases with smart set up not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you rewrite alaways content of div because you don't stop propagations.

I fix your problem with this code:

```
    var oldCellContent = $('#elementId').text();
     var newButtons = '<button class="btn btn-default complete">Complete?</button><button class="btn btn-default  delete">X</button>';
    $("#elementId").click(function(){
    $(this).html(newButtons);
    });
$("#elementId").on("click","button.complete",function(e){

        console.log('The complete function fired.');
        $('#elementId').text('Completed');
        e.stopPropagation();

    });
    $("#elementId").on("click","button.delete",function(e){
        console.log('The cancel function fired.');
        $('#elementId').text(oldCellContent);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! It does look like stopPropagation() was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to all of this is wrap the "New" text in it's own element and put the "show buttons" click handler on that element and simultaneously hide "new".

Code will be much simpler and there won't be any propagation issues or need to use off() and then add same handler again.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I think that does make sense. Thank you for the suggestion on how I could handle things better.

Comment: Take a look at this and tell me which way seems cleaner and easier to follow:  https://jsfiddle.net/pn1q658w/7/  Doesn't have much button functionality but it keeps things separated

Comment: Wow, yeah - that's lots better!

Comment: Then if you have to repeat this...can use `clone()` to make copies and insert at will